# Unity2D object following joystick

Tags: c#, 2d, game-physics, joystick, unity3d-2dtools

So I have a player. It has hands attached made from two rectangles.(I attached .GIF) 
[image: The playerObject following joystick input.]

So I need it to move how the player moves right stick on joystick. I made some controls, but I think they are poor, and inaccurate. I believe, it's possible to make it better. Hope I will find some help here. What I made up is an object (invisible, visible only for describing problem, debuging purposes) that moves on axis of joystick. Then there are player, he has hands. On the lower hand lower there is script attached. Before I had made spring, but I didn't liked result. Script:

```
    public GameObject Target;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.J)) {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.transform.position, 1);
    }
```

So the question is, how to upgrade this system hands control system? I would like it to be more physical, because I'm making a volleyball game.

Comment: Look into having a RigidBody with joints. Use Physic objects for objects that should behave in a physical fashion, so if those two rectangles are just rectangles you'll have to go a different approach.

Comment: They aren't just rectangles. Both have rigidbody and hinge joints. They are connected to body with them. What I want to do, is to control arms, or two rectangles with joystick.

Comment: So how would you need to "upgrade" the hands control system? The gif shows legit hands, other than not limiting the range of movement.

Comment: I don't like the result, because I get an little bit inaccurate controls and when they are being held in some positions, the other object (Ball) doesn't bounce off them (Both have physicMaterials with bounciness on 1 and friction 0).